# Is this the part of the door or the part of the framework?

Tags: meaning

The tutorial [is showing](https://youtu.be/dPzbuEunSLk?t=138) a door within its framework (img_1).

[image]

a few seconds later, this perspective (img_2) shows up.

the part pointed out by red circle is the framework, the part pointed out by blue circle is the door, how about the part pointed out by green circle?

Is this the part of the door or the part of the framework?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a technical rather than a linguistic question. What you call a door is actually a window. The frame forms part of the window.

Comment: The thing called a 'framework' in the question is actually called a **frame**, or a **window frame**.